# How to add Image Dynamically android

Tags: android, uiimageview

I Am Having Base class which is called common activity,In that i am returning the String in every activity.By using the following code.

```
txtHeader = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtHeaderText);
        txtHeader.setText(getScreenHeader());
```

and i am returning the empty string

```
protected String getScreenHeader(){
        return "";
    }
```

In another activity i will do in this way.

```
public  final static String SCREEN_NAME = "Dashboard";
@Override
    protected String getScreenHeader() {
        return SCREEN_NAME;
    }
```

How can i do this For IMAGE-VIEW.

Sorry for my English.

Thansks,
Nikhil.

Comment: not getting the question

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use a Bitmap object such as this:

```
 Bitmap b = getBitmapImage();
 ImageView img = (ImageView )findViewById(R.id.imgView);
 img.setImageBitmap(b);
```

Comment: Then you need to explain what you do need.